# count number of elements between "this" and "that" element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to know how "far" away a clicked element in the DOM is to a certain other element.

```
<li>item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
<li class="active">item3</li>
<li>item4</li>
<li>item5</li>
<li>item6</li>
<li>item7</li>
```

So when a user clicks an element it should return the distance to the active element: So `item1: return -2`, `item4: return 1`, `item6: return 3`, and so on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387560/find-number-of-nodes-between-two-elements-with-jquery

Comment: Other than that ^, you can always get a list of the elements and then just traverse it, incrementing a counter for each element and then simply break whenever you hit the element you need.

Comment: @Daniel No, no, I didn´t mean it like it was the same. I thought it might be of at least some use, since it´s quite similar to what OP wanted :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you could do it  the [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method...

Something like this:

```
var value = $('li').index() - $('li.active').index();
```

Comment: Simple and sweet! Minor modifications to make it work inside a `click` function: `$(this).index() - $(this).siblings(".active").index()`

Comment: @peirix If the user clicks on the active LI, then `$(this).siblings(".active").index()` will return `-1`, so the calculation will be incorrect. In your particular case, clicking on the active LI would return `3` (`2 - (-1) = 3`), as if item6 was clicked...

Comment: There's already a check on that at an earlier point in the code, so it won't run this code if `active` is clicked. But thanks for pointing it out, nice to know (:

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
$( ul ).delegate( 'li', 'click', function () {
    var idx1 = $( this ).index(),
        idx2 = $( this ).siblings().andSelf().filter( '.active' ).index();

    var distance = idx1 - idx2;

    // do stuff with distance
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/aeEBP/