# How to get number of index's a element is away from a certain element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Suppose I have the following HTML code:

```js
// post the jquery code here...
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="perspectiveSlider__main">
  <div class="perspectiveSlider__slidesContainer">
    <div class="perspectiveSlider__item item-left-faded">
      <img src="img/slide-1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="perspectiveSlider__item item-left">
      <img src="img/slide-2.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="perspectiveSlider__item item-center">
      <img src="img/slide-3.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="perspectiveSlider__item item-right">
      <img src="img/slide-5.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="perspectiveSlider__item item-right-faded">
      <img src="img/slide-6.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see `perspectiveSlider__item` are 5 siblings of each other and each also has a unique class, now how do I find the number of index's `.item-left-faded` is away from `item-center` ?

I know jQuery provides a `next()` and `prev()` functions and also `index()` function but is there something that I can create that will work like a `ProvideMeTheIndexTheSelectedElementIsAwayFromTheTargetedElement()` ?

In the above case `.item-left-faded` is away from `item-center` by 2 index's , How do i achieve this functionality ?

Comment: Can you share your JQeury code which one you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [count number of elements between "this" and "that" element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333258/count-number-of-elements-between-this-and-that-element)

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log($('.item-right-faded').index()-$('.item-center').index());
```

Read the doc :- https://api.jquery.com/index/

Answer (score 1):

Store your elements to an array with index and find your required classes and subtract indexes between them

here are code snippet to perform my thought

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var allItems = [];

  $('.perspectiveSlider__item').each(function(){
    allItems.push({ index: $(this).index(), className:$(this).attr('class').replace('perspectiveSlider__item ','') })
  })

  function ProvideMeTheIndexTheSelectedElementIsAwayFromTheTargetedElement(fromClass,toClass){
    var fromIndex = allItems.filter(function(item){      
      if(item.className == fromClass){        
        return item.index;
      }
    });


    var toIndex = allItems.filter(function(item){
      if(item.className == toClass){
        return item.index;
      }
    });    

    return fromIndex[0].index - toIndex[0].index;

  }  
  console.log(ProvideMeTheIndexTheSelectedElementIsAwayFromTheTargetedElement('item-left-faded','item-center'));  

})
```

Please let me know your issue is solve?

Comment: It looks like it will work, but you should add some explanations. E.g that it caches the indexs once when to DOM is ready. And it might not be a realoiable solution, because it would fail if the classes are changed dynamicly and `.attr('class').replace('perspectiveSlider__item ','')` would fail if the OP decides to change to order of the classes or adds addidional ones.

Comment: @t.niese you are correct on your point but this is thaught now author should decide how he will fit this thought to his solution. And make things working for him.